# Linux Version of Z3: Dependency On Old libgmp.so.3

Tags: z3

Z3's dependency on libgmp.so.3 is unresolved in the linux package, leaving the user to provide this library.  However, this library is very old and is not readily available.

Does anyone know a method for getting around this issue?  I am currently running x86_64 and cannot get around this missing dependency without a great deal of hassle.

Is it possible the linux packages could be fixed such they include the expected library in the distribution?

Answer (score 1):

You can get GMP3 by executing `sudo apt install libgmp3-dev`.
I'm not a Linux expert, but this is the command I used to install GMP before I compiled Z3.
When I installed the virtual machine for running Linux 64, I think I didn't find a package for the more recent versions of GMP.
I will try again. If it doesn't work, I will download the most recent GMP tar ball and build it from scratch.

BTW, the Z3 for Linux 32 comes with two .so files. One of them has GMP statically linked.
The trick I used for building this .so file didn't work for the 64 bit version.
As I said, I'm not a Linux expert, any suggestions on how to build a better Z3 library for Linux x86_64 users are welcome.

Comment: At least for the latest version of Ubuntu (11.10) this libgmp3-dev is a dummy package which points to the latest libgmp.  I will try downloading a 32 bit version of Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and try again.

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 has the proper combination of glibc and libgmp (installed as you specified).